# Rashi on Nach in English and with Nekudos

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach, rashi, english

Where can I find/buy Sifrei Nach with Rashi translated into English and (even better) the Rashi with nekudos?

Comment: To clarify, are you preferably looking for a Rashi with nekudot, and if that isn't possible, a Rashi without nekudot that at least has a translation? Or are you preferably looking for a Rashi with both nekuddot and English, and if that is not possible, a Rashi with an English translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Judaica Press *Nach* series (with the pink and red dust covers)](https://www.judaicapress.com/products/prophets-neviim-joshua) has every *Rashi* rendered into English. It does not vowelize the original Hebrew text of *Rashi*. (This is my experience, having used a few of the volumes. Make sure before you buy.)

[The same translation is on `chabad.org`](//chabad.org/15785), but in some (all?) cases without the original Hebrew text of *Rashi*.

Comment: Hmm. I have this set. I never noticed the English Rash"i translation, ther. At any rate, this is, indeed a great set. I know that there is a brown set for the Torah - I think produced by Art Scroll. It translates RAsh"i by phrases. I don't know if they have done the same for all Nac"h books.

Comment: @DanF - the cover of the books lead one to believe the Rashi is translated

Answer (score 1):

Sefaria has Rashi with nekudos and translated into English

https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.1.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he

Metsudah has also put out Nach with Rashi with nekudos and translated.

[https://www.amazon.com/Metsudah-Tanach-Book-Melachim/dp/B000PVSWS6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000PVSWS6)